# Contar ocorrencias de certos caracteres nos valores de uma coluna

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Bom, eu tenho um dataframe nesse estilo só que bem maior e as siglas de abreviação dos estados se repetem por toda a coluna, alterando apenas os valores em X, fazendo com que cada valor de uma linha seja único.

| index | Numbers |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | XXMGXXXX |
| 1 | XXSPXXXX |
| 2 | XXDFXXXX |
| 3 | XXSPXXXX |

O que eu preciso fazer é contar a frequência em que essas siglas de estado se repetem ao mesmo tempo que vou preenchendo outra coluna com esses valores, mais ou menos assim

| index | Contador | Numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | XXMGXXXX |
| 1 | 1 | XXSPXXXX |
| 2 | 1 | XXDFXXXX |
| 3 | 2 | XXSPXXXX |
| 4 | 2 | XXMGXXXX |
| 5 | 1 | XXRJXXXX |
| 6 | 3 | XXMGXXXX |

Cada sigla tem sua própria contagem.
Eu tentei utilizar o

```
df.groupby().count()
```

Porém esse método só faz a contagem da frequência dos valores em si, não sei como utilizar esse mesmo método para a contagem da frequência de um grupo de caracteres nos valores da coluna. Se for possível assim eu vou ter a frequência total em que cada sigla aparece, me permitindo utilizar o valor total para preencher a coluna 'Contador'.
Se não for possível, alguém tem uma luz de alguma outra forma de fazer isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver utilizando o [pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), ficando assim

```
df.insert(0, 'Contador', '')
df['Contador'] = df.groupby(df['Numbers'].str[2:4]).cumcount() + 1
```

A primeira linha apenas adiciona a coluna 'Contador' ao dataframe, na posição zero, e sem nenhum vazia.
Na segunda, passamos para o groupby o critério que queremos para criar os grupos individuais, que no caso são as siglas dos estados contida na string de cada linha da coluna 'Numbers', e para realizar a contagem individual desses grupos, de forma que ela vá se acumulando por todo o dataframe utilizamos o cumcount(), o count() não acumula a contagem por isso não da certo, o +1 é apenas para começar a contagem em 1 e não em zero.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).